# Como acomodar dos input uno al lado del otro?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Hola he intentado tener dos input, uno al lado del otro con su respectiva etiqueta, sin embargo me lo pone uno abajo del otro, les pongo la imagen de como me sale y el código que estoy usando.

Muchas gracias !!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="mb-3" style="float: right; width: 47%; margin-left: 2%;">
   <label class="form-label required bold">Aumento de crédito decomendado de</label>
      <input style="width: 30%;" type="text" class="form-control" name="example-text-input" placeholder="">
      <label style="float: right; position: relative;">
          <span>a</span>
          <input style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" type="text" class="form-control" name="example-text-input" placeholder="">
      </label>
```

Comment: Por que haces que tu div sea flotante?, por cierto trata aumentando el ancho que le asignas, puede que se muestren hacia bajo por que ya no caben

Comment: Saludos. En https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid y seguido abajo https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row muestran la forma en que corresponde para lo que buscas. Pruebalo sin los style que defines.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio bastante bien lo de bootstrap, Saludos !!

Answer (score -1):

```html
    <style>
       form{
           display: inline-block;
       }
        div{
           display: inline;
        }
    </style>
    <form>
       <div class="mb-3" style="float: right; width: 47%; margin-left: 2%;">
       <label class="form-label required bold">Aumento de crédito decomendado de</label>
          <input style="width: 30%;" type="text" class="form-control" name="example-text-input" placeholder="">
          <div>
               <label style="float: right; position: relative;">
              <span>a</span>
              <input style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" type="text" class="form-control" name="example-text-input" placeholder="">
          </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por el apoyo amigo !!

Comment: No debes cambiar el atributo global de todos los elementos `div` con CSS de esa forma, deberías usar un identificador o una clase como `.d-inline`, agrega además contexto a tu respuesta, procura no responder únicamente con código.